# Display ao aplicar Hover via CSS

Tags: css

Eu quero, que quando eu passe o mouse em cima da `li`, a `div` empresaMenusEsqhover fique como `display:block`.
Eu posso fazer isso em Jquery, porém, quero fazer o máximo que eu conseguir via CSS.

Tenho o HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Apresentação</h3>
        <div style="display:none" class="empresaMenusEsqHover"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Perfil da Empresa</h3>
        <div style="display:none" class="empresaMenusEsqHover"></div>

    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Histórico</h3>
        <div style="display:none" class="empresaMenusEsqHover"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Mercado de Atuação</h3>
        <div style="display:none" class="empresaMenusEsqHover"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.empresaMenusEsq{
    width: 228px;
    height: 145px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: white;
}
.empresaMenusEsq li h3{
    font-family: "Open-Sans-SemiBold";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.empresaMenusEsq li:hover{display: block;}
.empresaMenusEsqHover{
    background-image: url("../imagens/empresaMenusEsq.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 248px;
    height: 29px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem a ordem trocada, deve ser `li:hover .empresaMenusEsqHover` e não `.empresaMenusEsqHover li:hover`, e tem de fazer override com `!important` uma vez que aplicou o `display: none` diretamente no elemento.

```
li:hover .empresaMenusEsqHover  {
    display: block !important;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le7ckme0/)

À esquerda tem os parentes, para a direita tem os descendentes. Assim, o ultimo à direita deve ser a div com a classe `empresaMenusEsqHover`, e o `:hover` é feito sobre o `li` que está visivel. O importante aqui é usar o `!important`.

Ou melhor, se puder tire o `diplay: none;` do HTML e coloque:

```
li .empresaMenusEsqHover  {
    display: none;
}
```

para esconder, e o código em cima para o `:hover`. Se usar só CSS como sugiro aqui, pode tirar o `!important`. Se não conseguir mudar o HTML, tem de o usar.

Comment: No meu caso seria `.empresaMenusEsq ul li h3:hover .empresaMenusEsqHover{display: block;}
`?

Comment: @FelipeStoker, juntei mais info à resposta. Respondeu à pergunta que colocou aqui no comentário?

Comment: Deu certo @Sergio, muito obrigado

Comment: @FelipeStoker, exato! Vai ter de fazer ajustes à altura, e ter algum texto para mostrar, agora está vazio. mas é isso. http://jsfiddle.net/Le7ckme0/2/